# Adding Wordnet.net dictionary in c#

Tags: c#, .net, ms-word

How can I add Wordnet dictionary or msword dictionary in my application? I am developing the Application in .NET C#.

Comment: What do you mean by "add [a dictionary] in my application"? Are you looking for spell checking functionality?

Answer (score 1):

I assume u want to add spell checking?

if so there are a few options

using the MS Word

- Use the word spell checker
  http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/spellcheckdemo.aspx
  http://www.codeproject.com/KB/office/SpellCheckUsingWord.aspx
- using the built in WPF spell checker (if u are using wpf)
  http://www.dev102.com/2008/03/25/customize-spellcheck-on-wpf-text-controls/
- use a free source one
  http://sourceforge.net/projects/netspell/
- purchase one
  http://www.wintertree-software.com/spell-check/csharp/index.html
  http://www.keyoti.com/products/rapidspell/dotnet/

Can you give some more info on your requirements?

Comment: thannnxx but i want to search for meaning of any word with the help of dictinary. My application is like it will help the user to open up a file (using windows form) to read. And if the user come across with any difficult word,so the user can click on that word and find the meaning of it.Like MSWOrd

Answer (score 0):

As far as I was aware MS Word does not have a true dictionary. It has a spellchecker and a thesaurus.

Do you mean you want a thesaurus?

If you want a true dictionary perhaps you can look at doing a callout to a dictionary webservice like this one
http://services.aonaware.com/DictService/

Answer (score 0):

You could look at using the WordNet data files in your application, they are just text files that seem to follow a pretty basic structure. If you download the windows app you can see the data files it uses. Alternativly you could import them into a database (through SSIS or other means) to make life easier for yourself when coding:

- SQLite -> Self contained single file
  database which you can query through
  your .NET app
- Sql Express -> Free version of SQL Server you could deploy with your
  app.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do spell checking, hyphenation in :NET or need a thesaurus, you can give NHunspell a try. It is a .NET version of the OpenOffice, Google Chrome and Firefox spell checker Hunspell and has all these features. It can use the OO dictionaries.

[NHunspell Project Homepage](http://nhunspell.sourceforge.net/)

Answer (score 0):

For those who view this question, please refer to the following 
[link](http://wordnet.princeton.edu/wordnet/related-projects/#.NET). It points various C# implementations that read the WordNet database.

Answer (score 0):

Of the API's listed here: http://wordnet.princeton.edu/wordnet/related-projects/#.NET,
Matt Gerber's ( http://ptl.sys.virginia.edu/ptl/members/matthew-gerber/software#WordNet_API ) is the best.

It's not a great API, but it works okay and it was a good start for what I needed.

I've also not tried [Proxem's Antelope](http://www.proxem.com/Default.aspx?tabid=119) yet as it seemed more like a heavyweight app then a simple API.  It may be much more robust though.

There's also a SharpWordNet library as part of the [SharpNLP](http://sharpnlp.codeplex.com/) project that I haven't tried yet.